# Crash after pop'ing stack while a threaded NSURLConnection is open

Tags: multithreading, uinavigationcontroller, nsurlconnection

Error Log says:
bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x3c689f0: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...

App structure:
worker threads are detached from the MainThread as new data is needed via user interaction, each worker thread feeds data into its own slot in an array.  The problem arises only when I use the NavigationController to go "back" to the previous view WHILE a thread is still gathering data.  I've tried to send a [NSThread exit] to each thread upon viewWillDisappear thats not going to work...

Any suggestions on thread clean-up upon poppin' the view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently i needed to build in checks to the runloop as well as the didRecieveData loop to watch for a global variable to indicate if the view has disappeared.  This in turn needs to toggle the global var, causing all open threads to cancel the connection as well as exit the thread.